# How to write zsh autocomplete that replaces last argument?

Tags: shell, autocomplete, zsh

I want to provide an autocomplete that will search for results online. The idea is that user enters some search term, presses tab, and gets results of an online search based on that term. The results don't necessarily begin with the term user entered, or even contain it (more likely that their descriptions contain the term).

Here's an illustration of possible flow:

1. User enters search term and presses `tab` to trigger autocompletion

```
$ bookmark hello<tab>
```

2. Autocomplete erases entered search term (because we search by description, not information that we want to enter), makes a network request, and presents autocomplete options.

```
$ bookmark 
www.hellomagazine.com                      -- HELLO! - Daily royal, ...
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_(Adele_song)   -- Hello (Adele song) - Wikipedia
...
```

3. User selects one of possible options

```
$ bookmark www.hellomagazine.com
```

Is this a good approach at all? Maybe things like this are usually done using a different pattern?

So I've encountered a few problems while doing it:

1. When I use `_arguments` to present possible answers, zsh filters them by term that user already entered. Probably I need to erase entered last word first? How do I do it?
2. Zsh sorts the results alphabetically, bu I want to present them by relevance (in order that I pass them to `_arguments`). How to do it?
3. Zsh makes multiple network requests for the same term. First time user presses tab it makes a request but doesn't present suggestion list yet. On the second tab press the list of options is presented but it needs to repeat the same slow network request to do it. How do I cache or present results list the first time?

Comment: Erasing the user input is a bad UX in my opinion. Autocomplete is meant to (as the name suggests) _complete_ user's input, not replace it. Consider that in your design.
Imagine the user had a typo (typed "Held" instead of "Help"). Erasing the input and displaying some irrelevant suggestions would be most annoying. The user would have to start typing "Help" all over again. A big no-no! You could emulate what git's autocompletion for zsh does: The user is presented a list (do not erase the input yet) and when they select something with ENTER, you replace their initial input with the selection.

Comment: `Is this a good approach at all?` I would say no. *It violates the principle of least surprise.* I don't want something calling out to the internet because I press tab. Can it even be interrupted easily (ctrl+c)? Why not just have an `-s` flag for search, and a regular interactive menu? Deleting input is also a bad idea. It's a reference for the current command and for history. Control sequences can also cause problems.

Comment: There is precedence in the completion system for replacing user input with something different: `kill zsh<tab>` will replace the `zsh` process name with the PID of a `zsh` process.